# How to type guard on a 2D array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I tried to write some code like this:

```
const x: string[] | string[][] = blah();
if (Array.isArray(x[0])) {
    // I expect x to be inferred to be string[][] here, but it's not!
}
```

How come this doesn't infer `x` to be a 2D array? Am I doing something wrong, or is TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there isn't a ways to type guard those particular unions. That said you can create a custom type guard function quite easily:

```
/** Custom type guard */
const isArrayArray = (x): x is string[][] => Array.isArray(x[0]);

const x: string[] | string[][] = [];
if (isArrayArray(x)) {
    // x:string[][]
  x;
}
```

## More

user defined guards covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html