# check what exact type a variable is when type is (type1 | type2)

Tags: typescript

If I have a type which looks like this:

```
coord: number | Position | Position[] | Position[][]
```

How can I check what exact type a variable is? so if it is Position or Position[][]?

so that I can later do something like:
if (variable is type1) then do xyz,
else if (variable is type2) then do zyx

Thanks a lot!

Comment: One option is to write a zod-schema for each possible value, and then a function that runs each schema until it finds one that matches. https://github.com/colinhacks/zod

Comment: What *is* `Position`?

Comment: Check out if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812128/how-to-type-guard-on-a-2d-array-in-typescript) helps.

Comment: TypeScript cannot help you here. At runtime, `coord` is a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) or something else, depending a lot of how the definition of `Position` looks like.

Comment: I would not store values of four types in a single properties. Make 4 properties, one for each type of data then check them in a certain order and get the first value that is defined. Or, keep it as is and add another property that tells which type is actually stored in `coord`. This way the code is clear and there is no ambiguity.